# Подсчет количества общего записей по дням

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Есть таблица вида:

```
id | time1
 1 | 01-02-2019
 2 | 01-02-2019
 3 | 01-02-2019
 4 | 02-02-2019
 5 | 02-02-2019
 6 | 03-02-2019
```

Нужно посчитать общее количество записей за заданную дату. **В результате нужно получить такой ответ:**

```
3 | 01-02-2019
5 | 02-02-2019
6 | 03-02-2019
```

Пробую так:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, time1 FROM users group by time1 order by time1
```

Но получаю количество записей за каждый день:

```
3 | 01-02-2019
2 | 02-02-2019
1 | 03-02-2019
```

Как изменить запрос чтобы получить нужный результат?

Благодарю:)

Comment: Если "За заданную дату", то ваш запрос возвращает именно это. А вот в примере что вы указали, это не "за дату", а "количество записей за все предыдущие даты". И это либо надо решать через переменные, если ваша версия mysql не подерживает оконные функции, либо таки оконными функциями (https://habr.com/ru/post/268983/), если поддерживает. Так что стоит указать версию MySQL

Comment: mysql версия 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Накопительные итоги в MySql 5.7 можно считать с помощью переменных, примерно так:

```
SELECT @cnt:=@cnt+count AS count, time1
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, time1
      FROM users, (select @cnt:=0) x
     group by time1
  ) x
 order by time1
```

Comment: 0.o Благодарю, @Mike, то что нужно!:)

Comment: возможно подскажете еще 1 момент: как ограничить выборку по датам с учетом предыдущих записей? `SELECT @cnt:=@cnt+count AS count, DATE_FORMAT(time1,'%d-%m-%y') AS time1
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, DATE_FORMAT(time1,'%d-%m-%y') AS time1
      FROM users, (select @cnt:=0) x
     WHERE time1 between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) and (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) group by 2
  ) x
 order by 2` - за последние 14 дней.

Comment: @АлексейБондарь Так вы ее как раз и ограничили, берете даты за последние 14 дней (относительно сегодняшней). Вот если бы вы хотели за 14 дней относительно выводимой даты, тогда бы подход к запросу был бы совсем иным. Я бы тогда взял внутренний запрос просто как источник дат, и к нему выполнил join исходной таблицы, подходящих по датам строк для того же пользователя.